# parse xml with specific declaration

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, parsing

Hi I have attempting to parse xml using this link:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

however, when i attempt to follow it, I am getting this issue

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> tree = ET.parse('sitemap.xml')
>>> root = tree.getroot()
>>> print(root['loc'])
element indices must be integers
```

I am attempting to parse the `loc` value from this sitemap.xml declaration:

```
<root>
  <url>
    <loc>HTTPS://website.com/</loc>
    <lastmod>2022-10-10</lastmod>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://website.com/search/</loc>
    <lastmod>2022-10-10</lastmod>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://website.com/auth/user/</loc>
</root>
```

**UPDATE**
I can get it to print out a single `loc` value via:
print(root[0][0].text)

however, I want to loop through all of these `loc` fields and print them out - how can i do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
tree = ET.parse('sitemap.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for url in root:
    for child in url:
        if child.tag == 'loc':
            print(child.text)
```

Note that this will only work if the xml is in the exact format you provided (e.g. all of the `loc` tags are direct children of the `url` tags).